# How can i display Mysql entries in a specific order

Tags: php, android, mysql

In my android app i am trying to view a list of friends in the order of who is online and who is not 
The code i am using to do it is extracting the request flag (1) from friends table and then use the friend_id to get data from users table and use json_encode to send data back to app in order to display it , the order of friends is displayed in the same order they are in users table :
Here is the code :

```
if(isset($_POST['list_friends'])) {
    $sql = "SELECT friend_id FROM friends WHERE user_id='$user_id' && request='1'";
    $res = mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die(mysqli_error());
    $row_to_json = array();
    while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        foreach($rows AS $row) {
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='$row'
                    ORDER BY FIELD(is_online,'1') DESC";
            $res2 = mysqli_query($connection,$sql2) or die(mysqli_error());
            while ($rows2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2)) {
            //echo $rows_to_json = json_encode((object)$rows2);
                $row_to_json[] = (($rows2));
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode(($row_to_json));
}
```

is_online field is either (0 if offline and 1 if online)
Any idea of what is wrong in this code ?

**EDIT 1 :**

I tried this code :

```
    SELECT
  friends.friend_id,users.is_online
FROM friends INNER JOIN users ON friends.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  (friends.user_id = 21 and request = 1)
ORDER BY
 (users.is_online) DESC
```

I added `users.is_online` to check for the actual output of this field and this is what is got :
[image: Actual mysql result from query]

> Note that the actual is_online value exists in users table for `**22**` and
>   `**27**` is `**0**` not `**1**` !

**EDIT 2 :**

**

> Perfect :)

**

[image: Exactly what i need]

Comment: && should be AND in second line ?

Comment: @fahad anjum there is no problem in picking up entries flaged as (1) in request field , Data is extracted correctly , The issue is displaying friends in order .. nothing more

Comment: Could you pls. replace FIELD(is_online,'1') with just is_online DESC. https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-field-function.php

Comment: @FahadAnjum The manual on logical operators includes it and is perfectly valid https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks. I did not know about it.

Comment: One last thing: Depending on where your `$user_id` comes from, your code might be prone to SQL injection. I am assuming that `$user_id` is computed at another place in your code using safe methods, or that your code is meant only for testing. As a rule of thumb, always use parametrized statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @Fahad Anjum's comment in that `&&` is very unusual as `AND` operator in a `WHERE` condition. Having said this:

1) You could leave away the `FIELD()` function completely, i.e. write `is_online` instead of `FIELD(is_online, '1')`.

2) You are using strings where numbers would be sufficient (e.g. `user_id = '$user_id'` instead of `user_id = $user_id`).  This might be worrying and might cost performance due to implicit casts MySQL might have to do in those cases, and when it comes to the `FIELD()` function, might be the problem.

The MySQL documentation states:

> If all arguments to FIELD() are strings, all arguments are compared as
>   strings. If all arguments are numbers, they are compared as numbers.
>   Otherwise, the arguments are compared as double.

In your `FIELD()` function, you have a mixture of string (`'1'`) and number (`is_online`) arguments (you have stated that `0` and `1` are possible values of `is_online`, i.e. `is_online` contains a number).

I am asking myself what happens when MySQL compares the string `'1'` with the number `1` after having converted both of them to `double`, or if something bad happens during the conversion. Theoretically, it should not be a problem because converting a number to `double` should give the same result as converting that stringified number to `double`, and because `1` can be represented exactly as a `double`, but I could imagine that we have a problem here. Unfortunately, I can't test it right now, but you could try writing `FIELD(is_online, 1)` instead of `FIELD(is_online, '1')`.

3) The main problem is: In your first query, you select friends of the user with the given `$user_id`. Then you are looping through these friends and for every friend are executing a query *against the user table* to find out if that user (friend) is online.

*That second query returns exactly one row each time; therefore, ordering is useless here.*

You will have to solve this problem by doing a join between the `friends` and the `users` table in the first place.

Since I have never used PHP, I am a bit reluctant to suggest code here (I don't want to make a fool of myself by publishing code in a language I know nothing about without even being able to test). But your query would resemble the following:

```
SELECT
  friends.friend_id
FROM
  (friends INNER JOIN users ON friends.friend_id = users.id)
WHERE
  (friends.user_id = $user_id)
ORDER BY
  (users.is_online DESC)
```

Please note that I have left away your second condition here (`request = '1'`) because I can't imagine what it means and it is not that relevant here. You can easily re-add it to the code above.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts ,I tried to use the query you provided but still i got the same results , friends are being displayed by the order of their presence in users table not by their online status !

Comment: You could verify if the query I proposed works correctly by typing it directly into the MySQL client (replacing `$user_id` by a real user id and adding `DESC` to the `ORDER BY` clause). I would be interested in the result.

Comment: I made an edit to the question , Please check it out

Comment: It's too late. I am a moron. This happens if you write code without having the software at hands to test it. I have made a mistake and now have updated my query. Could you please give the new code a try? Of course, the `JOIN` must be on `friends.friend_id = users.id` instead of `friends.user_id = users.id`.

Comment: Perfect :) Done

Comment: *"I agree with @Fahad Anjum's comment in that && is very unusual as AND operator in a WHERE condition. "* - There's nothing unusual. The manual on logical operators includes it and is perfectly valid https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/logical-operators.html

Comment: By saying unusual, I meant that I did not see it in any example on the net or in any question at SO yet, although it is valid. I do not know why it is used so rarely.